# How to fix 'Element type is invalid' error when using <Swipeable> in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

every time I use the  command I get this error

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import moment from 'moment';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import 'moment/locale/pt-br';

import commonStyles from '../commonStyles';

export default (props) => {
  const doneOrNotStyle =
    props.doneAt != null ? { textDecorationLine: 'line-through' } : {};

  const date = props.doneAt ? props.doneAt : props.estimateAt;
  const formattedDate = moment(date).locale('pt-br').format('ddd, D [de] MMMM');

  const getRightContent = () => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={style.right}>
        <Icon name="trash" size={30} color="#fff" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Swipeable>
      <View style={style.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => props.toggleTask(props.id)}>
          <View style={style.checkContainer}>{getCheckView(props.doneAt)}</View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View>
          <Text style={[style.desc, doneOrNotStyle]}>{props.desc}</Text>
          <Text style={style.date}>{formattedDate}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Swipeable>
  );
};

function getCheckView(doneAt) {
  if (doneAt != null) {
    return (
      <View style={style.done}>
        <Icon name="check" size={20} color="#fff" />
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return <View style={style.pending} />;
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#AAA',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  checkContainer: {
    width: '20%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  pending: {
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    borderRadius: 13,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#555',
  },
  done: {
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    borderRadius: 13,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#4d7031',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  desc: {
    fontFamily: commonStyles.fontFamily,
    color: commonStyles.colors.mainText,
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  date: {
    fontFamily: commonStyles.fontFamily,
    color: commonStyles.colors.subText,
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  right: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix import, you forgot add `Swipeable` after slash

```js
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';
```